# How to retrieve user details in like button callback function in facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried to retrieve logged in user name and location details in like button callback function.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
   FB.init({
           appId: 'XXXXXXXXX',
           status: true,
           cookie: true,
           xfbml: true,
           oauth: true
   });
   FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
         if (response.status === 'connected') {
             var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
             var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
         } 
      });      
   });
 };
```

**Updated Code:**

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
   FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    } 
   }, true);      
 });
```

But I couldn't able to retrieve user details. Is it possible to retrieve user details?

Comment: When you get data of user, be sure that your facebook application has suitable permission. See more about permissions here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5

Comment: put your login status check and api code outside event suscribe and check if it works.

Comment: I have put login status check outside subscribe event. No luck.

Comment: @downvoters, Please care to comment

Answer (score 0):

`FB.getLoginStatus()` is used to determine if a user has authenticated your app, you need to use `FB.api('/me'` to get the user details.

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function () {  
        FB.init({
            appId: 'XXXXXXXXX',
            cookie: true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
            // the session
            xfbml: true,  // parse social plugins on this page
            version: 'v2.2' // use version 2.2
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            });
        });
 };
```

Comment: I have added above code in my application. But console.log is not working. I have called getLoginStatus() function inside like button callback.

Comment: I have tested with your updated code. I have checked in my browser's console. No response but response came inside edge.create. I think control not going inside of getLoginStatus. My App version is 2.0.